# Caesar cipher python decryption

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher, encoder, decoder

I have issues when I'm trying to decode an encrypted message. It decrypts almost everything perfectly but particular lowercased letters don't decrypt properly. though it works when theyre UPPERCASE. What did I do wrong?

```
def decrypt():
        print("Heres our Caeser Cipher Decryption program.")
        encrpMsg = input("Enter the message you would like to decrypt: ").strip()
        print()
        decrpKey = int(input("Enter key to decrypt, a number 0-25: "))
    
        decryptedMessage = ""
    
        for i in range(len(encrpMsg)):
            if ord(encrpMsg[i]) == 32:
                decryptedMessage += chr(ord(encrpMsg[i]))
    
            elif ((ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) < 97 and ((ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) > 90)):
                temp = (ord(encrpMsg[i]))
                decryptedMessage += chr(temp)
    
            elif (ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) <65:
                temp = (ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) + 26
                decryptedMessage += chr(temp)
    
            else:
                decryptedMessage += chr(ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey)
    
        print(decryptedMessage)
```

KEY:13
OUTPUT:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmTUVWXYZhijklm
EXPECTED OUTPUT:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: And what is your target? Use Caesar for [a,zA..Z]?

Comment: @kelalaka If I change it to that code the outputs now aopqrstuvwxyzTUVWXYZ[\]^_`

Comment: Better use like this `elif ((ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) >= ord('A') and ((ord(encrpMsg[i]) - decrpKey) <= ord('Z'))):` I've forgot the equality.

Comment: Why do you need to handle the lowercase and uppercase. For some key your program will fail.